# WxPython wxSplitterWindow.SplitVertically always shows uneven split

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm trying to understand how to use the wxSplitterWindow class but can't seem to get a vertical split to be even (i.e. left and right panes each take up the same amount of space). According to the wxPython 3.03 documentation, wxSplitterWindow.SplitVertically has the following signature:

```
SplitVertically(self, window1, window2, sashPosition=0)
```

The last parameter `sashPosition` has the following description:

sashPosition - The initial position of the sash. If this value is positive, it specifies the size of the left pane. If it is negative, it is absolute value gives the size of the right pane. Finally, specify 0 (default) to choose the default position (half of the total window width).

From the description, I gather that passing a 0 for `sashPosition` splits the window in half with the left and right panes taking up equal space. However, when I run the following example program, I get a window with an uneven split where almost all of the left panel is hidden.

```
import wx

class SplitterFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='SplitterWindow example')

        # Create the main splitter window (to be split vertically)
        self.splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self)
        self.rightPanel = wx.Panel (self.splitter)
        self.rightPanel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.BLUE)
        self.leftPanel = wx.Panel (self.splitter)
        self.leftPanel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.RED)

        # Expecting an even split with this call        
        self.splitter.SplitVertically (self.leftPanel, self.rightPanel, 0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(0)
    frame = SplitterFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

I'm running Python v2.7.10 using wxPython v3.0 toolkit on a Windows 8.1 machine.

Comment: My test is `OK`.Did you install pywin extension ? X86 X64 ? My idea haven't access for hook windows forms.

Comment: Your code works a treat on Linux, same version of python, it has to be your environment.

Comment: I get the same behavior on Python 2.7, wxPython 3.0 on Windows 10. Maybe it's a bug or something we both did incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, by trial, and error I get that this modification solved the problem

```
self.splitter.SplitHorizontally(self.leftPanel, self.rightPanel, 100)
```

But this is dependent on the size of the frame.

I'm using wxpython version 3.0.0.0

Comment: That's not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is ancient, but in case anyone else has this issue:

From the wiki: https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.SplitterWindow.html#wx.SplitterWindow.SetSashGravity

> Notice that when sash gravity for a newly created splitter window, it is often necessary to explicitly set the splitter size using SetSize to ensure that is big enough for its initial sash position. Otherwise, i.e. if the window is created with the default tiny size and only resized to its correct size later, the initial sash position will be affected by the gravity and typically result in sash being at the rightmost position for the gravity of 1

Either set the size manually with `splitter.SetInitialSize(...)` (obviously frame size dependent)
or use `splitter.SetSashGravity(.5)` so they grow evenly.